# Immersion part of the flow out theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In flow out theorem:

> **Theorem 9.20:** Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold $S \subseteq M$ is an embedded $k$-dimensional submanifold and $V \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ is a smooth vector field that is nowhere tangent to $S$. Let $\theta: \mathfrak{D} \rightarrow M$ be the flow of $V$, let $\mathfrak{O} = (\Bbb R \times S) \cap \mathfrak{D}. $  Let $\Phi = \theta|_{\mathfrak O}$.

---

We want to show  $\Phi: \mathfrak{O} \rightarrow M$ is an immersion.

To do this we first restrict $\Phi$ to $\{0\}\times S$ and we know on the restriction $\Phi$ is embedding,the question is why after that restrction of $d\Phi_{(0,p)}$ on $T_pS$   is inclusion map:$T_pS \to T_p M$(I know since embedding it's an injective map but why inclusion?)

> since by composition $\Phi|_{(0,S)} = i\circ \pi|_{(0,S)}$ such that $i:S\to M$ is the embedding inclusion map ,$\pi|_{(0,S)}$ is the diffeomorphism between $S $ and $\{0\}\times S$ so by chain rule on the restriction $T_p S$. The $d \pi$ is exactly the identity map,so $d\Phi = d i\circ Id$ as the inclusion $T_p S \to T_p M$ correct?

By the way why after showing $\Phi$ in this restrction is embedding we can not direct argue that its differential is injection?Since we can only show on the restriction set it's injection correct?

Comment: I don't think $\Phi_{(0,p)}$ is a map. The symbol $d\Phi_{(0,p)}$ denote differential of $\Phi$ at $(0,p)$. Just like general notation $df_p$ for smooth function $f$. To show $\Phi$ is an immersion we need to show its differential injective at every point. The point above is only managed to show injectivity on $\{0\} \times S$.

Comment: @Si Kucing  ,Hi I have another question,that is for the flow,we know under the coordinate the flow has the ODE: $\frac{\partial \theta ^j}{\partial t}(t,p) = V^j(\theta(t,p))$ for any individual $p\in M$ ,correct?the question is why the initial condition for ODE can set to zero point that is ,$\theta^j = 0$?  Since we can always choose chart to make it zero correct?

Comment: Hi, friend I am not sure whether I misinterpret some concepts here ?

Comment: After reread the proof in the book, $\Phi^j(0,p) = 0$ because $p$ is the center of the chart.